# egrep for lines matching a pattern but exclude pattern from output

Tags: grep

Searched and cant find a similar question to this:

I am trying to use egrep on a file like the following:

```
ABCD(something):    Some very good code;
ABCD(somethingElse):    Some other very good code;
ABCD(somethingElseElse):    Some other very good code;
```

I want to produce output like the following:

```
    Some very good code;
    Some other very good code;
    Some other very good code;
```

I am using the following grep command:

```
egrep -RIn --color "ABCD(.+):" grep_log_test.txt
```

Which works but is also outputting the matched pattern.  How can I exclude the pattern from the output? I see the -o option but that just prints the patten match only...

Comment: sed to the rescue. I don't think you can do this with grep only

Comment: @InnocentBystander time to learn sed I guess! :)

Comment: this should do the trick: `sed 's/ABCD(.\+): *//'`. I can post it as an answer if you'd like

Comment: @InnocentBystander Wow, that worked great!  I am going to have to go over a sed tutorial.  And yes, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments above, sed is probably the best and easiest tool to use here, as in:

```
sed 's/ABCD(.\+): *//'
```

It uses the `s` command to match `ABCD(.\+): *` between first set of slashes and replace it with (empty string) between second set of slashes.